# OSX application consumes 400% CPU usage

Tags: macos, memory-leaks, xcode6, cpu

Mac application consumes 400% of the CPU usage,please see the screen short for the clear info.

After recent changes in the code base in the prime cause of this issue.Tried Analyse the code for the find out any cause of bugs.

I need some expert opinion to tackle this issue?

my envi:
Xcode version:6.3.1
OSX version: 10.10.3

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, this is not a discussion forum - you must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.